# can any one tell me that we can open a link in webview to play a video

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview, live

my probelm is how to play a video in a webview. i can setup a live french on 000webhost to stream in android.now the problem is how can i play in android using a webview... here is my code which can display a white screen i dont know why

```
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView1 ); //This is the id you gave
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this
                                           //if ROM supports Multi-Touch     
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM


    // Load URL
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://gumsuminnocent.host56.com/frenchchannel.html");
```

not working just white screen.
plz help me and Thanks in advance 
sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Use Webview, Create a string for html tags, add iframe tage and pass the height and width of the video and url. and load the string in webview

```
webView.loadData(strHTMLTags, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: can you help me i am not very expert in android as well as in html ?? :)  plz help